# Convert Listview from Winforms to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listview

Hi I am trying to convert my Winforms application over to WPF to merge it with another WPF application.

The main part I am stuck on is linking the data to my ListView columns, in Winform I have:

```
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        this.scanner.Scan();
        ControllerInfoCollection controllers = scanner.Controllers;
        ListViewItem item = null;
        foreach (ControllerInfo controllerInfo in controllers)
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(controllerInfo.IPAddress.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.Availability.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.IsVirtual.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.SystemName);
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.Version.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.ControllerName);
            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
            item.Tag = controllerInfo;
        }
    }
```

I cant seem to find a way to bind each of the controllerInfo pieces to its corresponding column.
This is my xaml code for my ListView1:

```
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IPAdress}" Header="IP" Width="65"/>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Availability}" Header="Availability" Width="60"/>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsVirtual}" Header="Virtual" Width="40"/>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SystemName}" Header="System name" Width="75"/>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Version}" Header="RobotWare" Width="60"/>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ControllerName}" Header="Controller Name" Width="100"/>
    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

Comment: Did you mention the source in the listview element? Also make sure you bind to an ObsevableCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a friendly advice, learn `MVVM` before writing a single line of code in wpf. To solve your problem here, you need not to touch `Items` property direcly on the `ListView`. Just set the `ItemsSource` as below and it will work.

```
    this.scanner.Scan();
    ControllerInfoCollection  controllers = scanner.Controllers;

    listView1.ItemsSource = controllers
```

Comment: Thank you! I am nearing a project deadline and need to convert this winforms to wpf. I will try to learn MVVM but time is of the essence.

Comment: I am now trying to convert my selected item to a listviewitem `ListViewItem item = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0]` I cannot find the correct explicit conversion to use or is my naivety doing me in again?

Comment: why do you need a listviewitem?

Comment: I'm just trying to convert it and that line had an error. The item is used in the rest of the event handler where if item!=null some things happen depending on its properties

Comment: If your listview is not multiselect then `ControllerInfo controller = listView1.SelectedItem as ControllerInfo` will give you selected controller... for multiselect `ControllerInfo controller = listView1.SelectedItems[0] as ControllerInfo` will give you first selected controller. There is no need for ListViewItem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654281/convert-object-to-listviewitem?noredirect=1#comment36334610_23654281